# dnx ef migrations add Initial dnx : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Any ideas on this?

My project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication1-c5682a65-7af3-447d-a812-9b4838ea33be",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Get the error when I try to run the migrations step

```
PM> dnx ef migrations add Initial
dnx : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
At line:1 char:1
+ dnx ef migrations add Initial
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Argument...cannot be null.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Parameter name: appEnv
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IApplic
ationEnvironment appEnv, ILibraryManager libraryManager, IRuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnv)
```

This is my dnvm list:

```
PM> dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                    Alias  
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                    -----  
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes default
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes
```

I was walking through this, but so far this new ASP.NET seems very buggy.
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

**Update**

dnu build output

```
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.3991506
Total build time elapsed: 00:00:01.4070482
Total projects built: 1
PM>
```

and dnu restore

```
PM> dnu restore
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CoreClr-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231

  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
Restoring packages for G:\Projectos\Tests\projx\project.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Threading.ThreadPool'
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Threading.ThreadPool' 722ms
Writing lock file G:\Projectos\Tests\projx\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 3023ms elapsed

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config

Feeds used:
    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
PM>
```

Comment: as a 3k rep user, you should at least have learnt how to post a proper question. Isn't it?

Comment: So you did the dnu build step and had no problems? And your dnu restore was similarly without issue?

Comment: I think your versions are wrong. Your default is showing as clr, even if the active is coreclr. Try to explicitly tell dnvm/dnu/dnx to use your active runtime - `dnvm exec 1.0.0-rc1-update1 dnu build` or perhaps update your -a flag to use the x86 instead of x64...

Comment: Edit: I think your versions are wrong. Your default is showing as clr, even if the active is coreclr. Try to explicitly tell dnvm/dnu/dnx to use your active runtime - `dnvm exec 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr dnu build` or perhaps update your -arch flag to use the x86 instead of x64...(ETA -r coreclr)

Comment: @NovaDev, it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moving my comment answer to the actual answer (and cleaning it up a bit) - It looks like the versions are wrong. The default is showing as clr, even though the active version is coreclr. In this case, I would recommend explicitly telling dnvm/dnu/dnx to use the active runtime with the active arch for your various build commands and such: `dnvm exec 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr dnu build` and possibly also update the `-arch` flag to use x86 instead of x64.